# show that these points form a sphere

Tags: calculus

Question: in d=3 let a and b denote two vectors and consider the points r in $R^3$ that satisfy (r-a) $^.$ (r-b) = 0. Show that these points form a sphere and identify the radius and center.

how does the dot product end up with an equation of a sphere?

Comment: Thales' theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $(r-a ) \cdot (r-b) = 0 $ means that the vectors $(r-a) $ and $(r-b)$ are perpendicular to each other.

Can you think of what vectors $r$ would satisfy this geometric interpretation? How does it relate to $a$ and $b$?

Comment: would you need to have the first r vector be b and the second one be a?